# How can i delete the highlight around ElevatedButton when mouse hover?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to delete the highlight around `ElevatedButton` when the mouse hover on it.

[image][image]

I tried to change `onPrimary`, `primary` and `onSurface` color but nothing is working.

```
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            elevation: 0.0,
            onSurface: PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR,
            primary: PRIMARY_BACKGROUND_CONTAINER_COLOR,
            onPrimary: PRIMARY_ON_HOVER_COLOR,
          enableFeedback: false
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Text("John Doe",style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR
                  )),
                  Text("Moderator",style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 10,
                      color: SECONDARY_TEXT_COLOR
                  ))
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Do you mean the highlight around the button when pressed?

Comment: @LakshanCosta i dont know what is called, border or shadow or highlight around the button, i want when the mouse hover on the button (before the click), i want change the color of the button but without that grey color like the photo above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What u are seeing is not the border but the elevation of the button. If u want something without elevation use `TextButton` instead
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html

Answer (score 0):

What mozes told is right.

It would be easier to create your own button in this case by using GestureDetector.

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap:(){
      //Your button's onClick
    }
    child: Container(
      decoration:BoxDecoration(
        color:Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),//Your radius
      )
      child:YourElevatedButtonChild() //ElevatedButton's child
    ),
  ),
```

If you want to give padding then wrap the Container's child with padding.